# Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve an optimization problem as shown below. But every time I get an error `Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`. 
Can anyone help me to see what is wrong here in the code?

```
def func(vec):

    linspec = -(kx**2)+((1.-nu)*(kx**4))
    lin = linspec*np.fft.fft(vec)
    nlin = np.zeros_like(lin)
    nlinre = vec*vec
    nlinspec = np.fft.fft(nlinre)
    nlin = (0.5*1j*kx*nlinspec)
    sol = lin+nlin
    rhs = np.zeros_like(sol, dtype='complex')
    sol -= rhs
    sol = np.fft.ifft(sol).real

    return sol

def kssol(u0):

    u1 = np.ones((2*Mx,), dtype='complex')
    #u1 = 100.*u0
    u = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, u1)

    return u
```

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) finds the root of functions from R<sup>n</sup> ↦ R. Your function `func` seems to be C<sup>n</sup> ↦ R, in particular the starting point `u1` has explicit complex type (though it's value is real), and that's exactly what the error is talking about.

If your input is always real, simply set `dtype='float'` in `u1`. Otherwise you'd have to use a different function for optimization, e.g. [`mpmath.findroot`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html) from sympy.